# Find the indices of false values in array and display them in an error

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have bunch of logical conditions to check. For each condition which is not satisfied, I need an error message. Here is my code for better understanding:

```
v1 = isequal(c{1, 1}, 'some string');
v2 = isequal(c{1, 2}, 0);
v3 = isequal(c{2, 1}, 'some string');
v4 = isequal(c{2, 2}, 0);
v5 = isequal(c{3, 1}, 'some string');
v6 = isequal(c{3, 2}, 0);

v = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6];
```

In the above code, some tests return false, so they are zeros (false) in `v`.

Now I want to get which ones are zero and flag them in an error. For example if v3 is false, I need a output showing `error('Check the v3 for solving')`.

I cannot use if conditions more than once also I need to get the value from `v`.

Comment: I need to now which one from that 6 is false so that I can write in error mesggage. My problem is how to find which one is false ?

Comment: sorry for not making clear. for example
i got a result v = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]. Is it possible to get a output telling v2,v3,v5 are false and error message as error('check v2,v3,v5'). if it is poosible then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do all of these comparisons on their own lines, you can use `cellfun`

```
c = {'test',        0 
     'some string', 1 
     'some string', 0};

V = cellfun(@isequal, c, {'some string', 0; 'some string', 0; 'some string', 0})

>> V = 3x2 logical
   [0 1 
    1 0
    1 1]
```

To get your `v`, you can make this into a vector

```
v = V(:); % v = [0 1 1 1 0 1].';
```

Then you can create your error message.

```
error(['Check: ' sprintf('v%d, ', find(~v)) 'did not match criteria'])

% Output in red (and stops function) as it is an error
>> Check: v1, v5, did not match criteria
```

---

Of course you can carry on creating `v` how you were, or skip the declaration `v = V(:)` and directly use `V(:)` instead of `v` in the `find` statement of the error.

Either way, this is basically a one-liner to create the error you want, using `sprintf`.

---

If your two checks really are always the same two values (like `'some string'` and `0`) you don't have to write them out every time either

```
V = cellfun(@isequal, c, repmat({'some string', 0}, size(c,1), 1))
```

---

You probably want to check there is at least one `false` value before you launch an error, do that using `any`...

```
if any(~v); error(['Check: ' sprintf('v%d, ', find(~v)) 'did not match criteria']); end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `find` function. You can read about it [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

In short, you could write:

```
idx = find(~v)
```

Which would give you the indices of the items which fulfill the given condition.
Further, this could be used to print the error info you need.

To display a message you could use:

```
disp(['problem with: ', num2str(idx)])
```

Which would print the proper info for all the indices of interest.

Comment: @Wolfie Sure `find(~v)` is the proper way, this was meant to be just an example. Nevertheless, edited. According to the provided link find should work for logical values as well `Data Types: single | double | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | logical | char`